# apcupsd doesn't show voltage with "SmartUPS 1000 LCD"

Tags: linux, ups, apcupsd, apc-smart-ups

I'm trying to config **apcupsd** on my Ubuntu 10.04 Server, I've got an `"APC Smart UPS 1000 LCD"` connected via USB ( `Bus 003 Device 003: ID 051d:0003 American Power Conversion UPS` ).

My `apcupsd.conf` file highlights:

```
UPSCABLE usb
UPSTYPE usb
DEVICE
```

And the `apcaccess` outputs is:

```
APC      : 001,024,0608
DATE     : Wed Feb 23 13:30:27 CET 2011
HOSTNAME : lnx-deb
VERSION  : 3.14.6 (16 May 2009) debian
UPSNAME  : lnx-deb
CABLE    : USB Cable
MODEL    : Smart-UPS 1000 
UPSMODE  : Stand Alone
STARTTIME: Wed Feb 23 13:30:26 CET 2011
STATUS   : ONLINE 
BCHARGE  : 100.0 Percent
TIMELEFT :  23.0 Minutes
MBATTCHG : 5 Percent
MINTIMEL : 3 Minutes
MAXTIME  : 0 Seconds
ALARMDEL : Always
NUMXFERS : 0
TONBATT  : 0 seconds
CUMONBATT: 0 seconds
XOFFBATT : N/A
STATFLAG : 0x07000008 Status Flag
SERIALNO : AS1041122281  
FIRMWARE : COM 02.1 / UPS.05.I
APCMODEL : Smart-UPS 1000 
END APC  : Wed Feb 23 13:30:31 CET 2011
root@lnx-deb:~#
```

How can I read others data that I can see on my UPS display?
Such as voltage in / out, load capacity and other stuff.

Thanks!

Comment: Somehow the apcupsd does not yet support the "lcd" generation of smart-ups, i think. I made the same observation, also the ''apctest'' program does not work for most options.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the apcupsd [CGI monitoring programs](http://www.apcupsd.com/manual/manual.html#apcupsd-network-monitoring-cgi-programs) where your webserver can use them?  Looks like the sample output at that link may be what you want.

Comment: No, but I'm running a `munin` plugin as server monitor, but I think that I'm using a wrong driver to access my SmartUPS 1000 LCD, or it's unsupported, in fact some `STATUS` variable are missing.

Comment: Why not try APC's Powerchute software for Linux?  Entering the UPS part number at http://www.apc.com/tools/download/index.cfm should point you to a compatible version. They make you register, but I think it's free.